# How do you take inputted characters and output them a certain number of times?

Tags: java, loops, methods, user-input, void

I have to write a program that takes two inputted characters and print them out `x` times using a method. With what I have so far, it will output numbers instead of the characters. How can I fix it?

```
int length;
char ch1;
char ch2;

System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
ch1 = input.nextLine().charAt(0); //input refers to scanner.
System.out.print("Enter second character: ");
ch2 = input.nextLine().charAt(0); //input refers to scanner.
System.out.print("Enter the length of the line: ");
length = input.nextInt(); //input refers to how many times the characters ar$
draw_line(length, ch1, ch2);

//Method starts here.

public static void draw_line(int length, char ch1, char ch2){
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        System.out.print(ch1 + ch2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time when you post a question please also try to make it as a complete working code - you obviously cut some part of it from a program and there were unbalanced brackets.

Comment: @sashkello I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because adding chars is not concatenation. Please see this question: [In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char)

What you want is a string containing two chars, probably the shortest edit is:

```
System.out.print("" + ch1 + ch2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the char to [`Character.toString(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29) to convert it to a `String`.

```
System.out.print(Character.toString(ch1) + Character.toString(ch2));
```