# Shifting a type char, similar assignments behave differently

Tags: java, type-mismatch, compound-assignment

Hi I have a piece of Java code that shifts a character by 2, like so

```
char ch = 'A';
ch += 2;
System.out.println(ch);
```

The output in this case is 'C' (as expected). But if I rewrite the code like this:

```
char ch = 'A';
ch = ch + 2;
System.out.println(ch);
```

I get a compilation error 'Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char'. Why is this happening, aren't the two assingments equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a common misconception that `X += Y` is identical to `X = X + Y`. From [JLS §15.26.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

Notice that there is an implicit cast involved. Now when you have something like:

```
ch = ch + 2;  // no cast, error
```

the type of the right-hand side is `int` while the type of the left-hand side is `char`, so there is a type mismatch between the two sides of the assignment, hence the error. This can be fixed with an explicit cast:

```
ch = (char) (ch + 2);  // cast, no error
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, do you know why `ch = ch + (char) 2;` doesn't also work?

Comment: @area5one Because the result of adding two chars is also an int. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char.