# if a word has an even amount of letters print the word with two letters per line?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoAtATime {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word with an even amount of letters:");
    String w = scan.nextLine();
    if(w.length() % 2 == 0) {
      for(int i= 0; i<w.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(w.charAt(i));
      }
    } else {
      System.out.println("You didnt follow directions");
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code so far and I can't figure out how to make it print two per line instead of one, any help?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it :

```
if (w.length() % 2 == 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i+=2) {
        System.out.print(w.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(w.charAt(i+1));
    }
}
```

Or you could do it with `String::substring`.

```
if (w.length() % 2 == 0) {
    for(int i = 0; i < w.length(); i+=2)
        System.out.println(w.substring(i,i+2));
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of problems, 1. adding chars does not concatenate them. 2. w.length() doesn't need to be divided by 2.

Comment: @NickG Thanks for the correction. I guess that's one of the risks of answering too fast. Fixed now.

Comment: Nice - I like the substring answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

Slight modification to @Eran's answer, you don't need to divide w.length() by 2. Also, adding the char's does not concatenate them.

```
String w = "12345678";
if (w.length() % 2 == 0) {
    for(int i= 0; i<w.length(); i+=2)
        System.out.println(""+w.charAt(i)+w.charAt(i+1));
}
```

Gives:

```
12
34
56
78
```

Reference: [In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the "for" loop to this:

```
 for(int i= 1; i<w.length(); i+=2){
     System.out.println(w.charAt(i-1) +""+ w.charAt(i));
 }
```

Comment: You might want to try testing this (it's wrong, unless I'm mistaken). For "12345678" I'm getting "12", "23", "34", etc.

Comment: Thank you. Had a typo there. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

you can use Google Guava which split your string by fixed length (2 in your case).

```
for(String subStr : Splitter.fixedLength(2).split(w)){
    System.out.println(subStr);
}
```

here is the java doc for [Splitter](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)