# Java: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to char

Tags: java

- char c = '1';
- char res = '0' + '1'; // no error
- char res2 = '0' + c; // compile error

The last line will throw compile error. Each part of the expression is char, why the expression itself is promoted to an int?

Thanks

Edit: Found why the 3rd statement failed. The reason is explained in 
[In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char)

But the knowledge that char + char = int does not explain why the 2nd of your three examples does compile. Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it's context sensitive..i.e. it will read a char as an int when arithmetic is the use case. Though don't quote me on it. Maybe my comment will anger someone enough to come out and correct us :)

Comment: (The duplicate is for `byte` rather than `char`, but it's basically the same)

Comment: Ah! Good guess on my part.

Comment: I'm not convinced that duplicate answers this. Try this: `char a = 60000;` `char b = 70000;`. The first compiles whereas the second one doesn't. That is because, even though the assigned values are both `int` literals, the compiler can see that the first does not exceed `Character.MAX_VALUE`. In your case, the difference between `'0' + '1'` and `'0' + c` is that, even though the addition is `int` addition for **both** cases, in the first case the compiler is able to see that the result does not exceed `Character.MAX_VALUE` because it is a constant expression. I think that's it anyway.

Comment: I believe I found the anser here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char thanks all

Comment: @paracicy But the knowledge that `char + char = int` does not explain why the 2nd of your three examples *does* compile. I don't think either of those posts are great duplicates for this.

Comment: @PaulBoddington good point. still need answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet is it possible to reopen this?

Comment: The second example is a compile-time constant within the relevant bounds of the type. Look at the JLS on constant values for more details. If you're interested in just that part, I'd create a new question - asking a question which has mostly been answered elsewhere, and adding emphasis on new parts later, doesn't really work well.

Comment: You want to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2 and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28