# Why the following program is printing numbers instead of alphabets

Tags: java

I am trying to print out all the possibilities of a given string for a fixed length 3. Here is my program

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        String input = "abc";
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;
        for(i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(j=0;j<3;j++){
                for(k=0;k<3;k++){
                   System.out.println(input.charAt(i)+input.charAt(j)+input.charAt(k)); 
                }
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

But it prints the permutations of numbers in this format. But I intend to print aaa, aab, aac, bbb .. in that fashion.

```
291
292
293
292
293
294
293
294
295
292
293
294
293
294
295
294
295
296
293
294
295
294
295
296
295
296
297
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char

Comment: Try concatenating `System.out.println(" "+input.charAt(i)+input.charAt(j)+input.charAt(k));`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @patel

Comment: Thanks for the resource @turon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input.charAt(i)` returns a `char`, which is an integer type. Therefore `+` performs `int` addition instead of concatenation of `String`s.

Adding an empty String at the start of the expression will solve your problem :

```
System.out.println(""+input.charAt(i)+input.charAt(j)+input.charAt(k));
```

Comment: Any idea how to make it generic? In the above code I explicitly wrote 3 loops, but in the run time if I ask the user to give the input string. Let's say he gave string of length 5, I can inject for loops dynamically right. Any solution?

Comment: @gates You can use a recursive method.

Comment: can you provide me some resource in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

`charAt` returns an integral type (actually a `char` which is a 16 bit unsigned integral type in Java). `+` is simply summing the values.

One way round that is to prefix the expression with an empty string literal: this forces Java to the interpret `+` as *concatenation*: `"" + input.charAt(/*etc*/`

In my opinion this is a flaw in Java permitting `+` to be used as a string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 1):

You used this line. That can solve your problem.

```
System.out.println(Character.toString(input.charAt(i))+Character.toString(input.charAt(j))+Character.toString(input.charAt(k)));

char a_char = input.charAt(0); // This is also return only a char
```