# Additive operator used with char values produces different results

Tags: java, charat

I am getting a strange return for the below block of code (sets of integer values):

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
String answer = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
answer = answer + (str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i));
}
return answer;
}
```

Opposed to the correct output value (a duplication of the strings chars) when I remove the parentheses enclosing the str.chatAt method calls in the first statement line of the loop:

```
answer = answer + str.charAt(i) + str.charAt(i);
```

Any help is appreciated, could not track down online.

Thanks

Comment: And more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char

Answer (score 0):

In Java `char` is an integral type. It appears you wanted `String` concatenation (that is `String` addition). You could use

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
    String answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        answer = answer + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i))
                + String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
    }
    return answer;
}
```

or (my preference) a `StringBuilder` like

```
public String doubleChar(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        sb.append(ch).append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Helpful - thank you very much