# Java += operator?

Tags: java, operators, string-concatenation

I originally learned that

`string += otherString;`
is the same as
`string = string + otherString;`

However, I found that `string += char1 + char2` will throw an exception while `string = string + char1 + char2` will not. When concatenating chars to strings I typically add an empty string so I don't get the exception, but why is that even necessary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710619/java-operators

Comment: Ah, looks like it was already asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char). The result of adding a char to another char is an int, which cannot be added to the String. Whereas with s = s + c1 + c2, the '+' operator associates left to right so the chars are converted to fit string concatenation.