# Why am I getting this Result?

Tags: java

```
char ch = '3';
result = cube(ch);
// Call the method that accepts a char
System.out.println("Cubed 'char' = " + result);
```

The method `cube`

```
private static char cube(char c) {
    char result;
    result = (char) (c *c *c);
    return result;
}
```

When I run this this code i get cubed 'char' = 1579, I would like to know where this number comes from within my code. Help!

Comment: `'3' == 51`. `51^3 == 132651`, which is larger than `Character.MAX_VALUE`; so it overflows.

Comment: No it's defined in Java.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char) related post.

Answer (score 8):

When you multiple `char`s together, [they are promoted to `int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17).

The `int` value of `'3'` is 51 (the ASCII value; as stated in [JLS Sec 3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1), the first 128 characters of UTF-16 encoding are the same as ASCII characters).

So `'3' * '3' * '3' == 51 * 51 * 51 == 132651`.

But `132651` is too large to fit into a `char` when you cast it; so it overflows (twice, since `Character.MAX_VALUE == 65535`), and you get the value

```
   (char) (c * c * c)
== (char) 132651
== (char) (132651 % 65536)
== (char) 1579
== 'ث'
```

But then you are assigning the result of the call to `cube` to an `int` (or `long`) variable called `result`; so it is promoted *again* to `int`, and then concatenated to the string: this means that the integer value is appended to the string, not the `char`. Hence:

```
Cubed 'char' = 1579
```

in the output.

Notice that if you call without assigning to `result`:

```
System.out.println("Cubed 'char' = " + cube(ch));
```

then the output is

```
Cubed 'char' = ث
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/CaPBUl)

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to say that '3' is a literal value for a `char` (a UTF-16 code unit) with the decimal value of 51? While term "ASCII" might be familiar to some, what the value for "3" is in ASCII has no bearing.

Answer (score 2):

A `char` in Java is a 16 bit unsigned type with a range 0 to 65535.

Your code `char ch = '3';` is actually assigning the value 51 to `ch`. (Java mandates ASCII for the first 7 bits of the `char` type and 51 is the ASCII value of the number 3).

Formally the multiplication happens just after the arguments to the muliplication are converted to `int`. The result, 51 * 51 * 51 is 132651 and is an `int` type. When you assign this to a `char`, Java will subtract as many 65536 values as are necessary to pull the result into the accepted range. So your answer is

51 * 51 * 51 - 65536 - 65536 which is 1579

Answer (score 1):

The number is the result of: (51^3) % (2^16)

Because, as andy says in a comment, 51 (ascii value of '3') ^ 3 overflows, so every multiple of 2^16 (character size in java) is discarded and only what is left is shown.