# add two char data type in java

Tags: java, char, ascii

case 1:

```
char c='A'+'A'; 
System.out.println(c);   // print question mark (?)
```

case 2:

```
char c1='A';
char c2='A'+c1;   // Compile time error
System.out.println(c2);
```

In case1 I have logic When I am adding two char literals, the sum of ascii value is printing which is equivalent to ascii value of question mark.
But in case2 why compile time error is showing that '*cannot convert from int to char*'

if char+char=int then this rule must be apply for both cases.

Comment: This question applies to all integer types where a narrowing conversion at runtime would be required. (And, that's the only way that this makes sense because what's the meaning of adding a UTF-16 code unit to a UTF-16 code unit?)

Answer (score 3):

In the first case two *final* chars are added and at compile time it is checked that the resulting int does not overflow a char.

In the second case one operand is not final, and the compiler refuses to do a sum.
A bit dumb, but considering multithreading and other cases, maybe justifiable. At least an easily understood rule.

Doing

```
final char c1 = '0';
char c2 = '1' + c1; // 'a'
```

should compile.

(It goes without say, that one should never do something like `'0'+'1'`.)

Comment: I suppose it would be possible to extend the definition of ["constant variable"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) to include "effectively final" variables initialized with ["constant expression"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) in addition to final ones, but as always there is a cost/benefit-tradeoff to consider

Comment: On second thought, such a change in the JLS would not be backwards-compatible because it would have implications on which code gets evaluated at runtime vs. compile time, which code is considered unreachable and - probably most difficult to fully anticipate all consequences of - the [class initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

Addition or 2 or more variables which are of type int or lower than int results in the type int.

So what you are doing with `char c2 = 'A' + c1;` is actually not giving you a char result. It is giving you int result which you are trying to implicitly type cast to byte, which gives you the compile time error.

> Summary
>   Char + Char = Int
>   And Char cannot directly store Int.

Try and do this instead
`char c2 = (char)('A' + c1);`

Here you explicitly type cast the int value to char type
Telling the compiler that you are ready to accept the ***Lossy Conversion*** that may happen

Comment: char + char = int is also applicable for first case. But case 1 is working fine.

Comment: In case 1 you are storing addition of **constants**  and not **char** variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case there is an error because, by [JLS 5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) both operands of the binary expression are converted to int.

To make it work you should add explicit cast:

```
char c2=(char)('A'+c1);
```

Comment: both operands of the binary expression are converted to int. is also applicable for 1st case. but it working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The result of adding Java chars, shorts, or bytes is an int

See the detailed answers on this post: 
[In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char/8688708)