# Java - why won't char '+' appear on the console?

Tags: java, char, println

I am making a simple calculator and here is my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 7;
    char w = '+';
    
    System.out.println(x+w+y+"="+(x+y));
}
```

The result appears as '53 = 10' and I don't get why '+' won't appear and where 53 came from. The correct result '3+7=10' appears when I use (w) instead of w at the last line.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char`s are implicitly convertible to integers in Java. `x + w + y` adds their values. The integer value of the character `'+'` happens to be 43, so you get 3 + 43 + 7 (= 53).

Putting the `w` into parentheses does *not* change that, contrary to what you said.

To fix this, make `w` into a `String`:

```
String w = "+";
```

Comment: The first key point is that `+` is left-associative, so `x+w+y+"="+(x+y)` is equivalent to `((((x+w)+y)+"=")+(x+y))`; the second key point is that `+` is string concatenation if either operand is a `String`, and numeric addition otherwise. `x+w` is therefore evaluated using numeric addition (a `char` is not a `String`), so it's `3 + 43 = 46`. Then `46 + y` is evaluated using numeric addition, giving `53`. Then `53 + "="` is the first subexpression to be evaluated using string concatenation, because `"="` is a String.

Comment: Wow thanks for such a kind comment! Really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4):

this behavior is due the fact that the  expression

```
x + w + y
```

is actually evaluated as `3 + 43 + 7`, why, you may want to know? well because `+` is a char which is actually a number and 43 is is't value as integer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Never knew that char could be a number!