# How to concatenate chars rather than add the numeric values

Tags: java

How to connect char number with char number?
My code is:

```java
String room = "901";
// I want to a new String "01" so i do this

String roomNum = room.charAt(1) + room.charAt(2); // it's error

String roomNum = h.charAt(0).concat(h.charAt(1)); // error too
```

When I use `String.valueOf()` it gives me an ASCII.

Comment: In Java a char is equivalent to a number between 0 - 65535. Adding two chars does not give a String, but a new number.

Answer (score 4):

```java
String room = "901";
//I want to a new String "01":
```

Use:

```
room.subString(1);
```

[`String#subString(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) returns substring starting with `int` and ending with the last character.

For more `subString` overloads, have a look at [String API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html).

---

If you want to *concatenate two chars*, you can do:

```java
String room = "901";

char a = room.charAt(1);
char b = room.charAt(2);

String result = String.valueOf(a).concat(String.valueOf(b));
```

Otherwise, `String roomNum = 'a'+'b';` will not compile, as [the result of adding Java chars, shorts, or bytes is an int](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8688708/1553537).

Beware, that `char` [represents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) an Unicode Character (in Java, 16-bits each). So, each `char` value, under the hood, is encoded by numeric value, which is stored as a hexadecimal, decimal or other radix-system number. This is the main reason, why arithmetic operation on `char` value promotes to `int`.

Comment: Thank you so much! i did not expect that method at that time :(

Answer (score 2):

While using `substring` will solve the problem (as in the answer of @Giorgi Tsiklauri), this doesn't point to the real hidden question posted that is:

*Why a concatenation between chars is not the same of a concatenation of two strings of size 1 ?*

That happens because the + symbol doesn't work as a concatenation in this context.

When you apply the `+` operator on chars a conversion to `int` is done before the operation. This operation is called [Binary Numeric Promotion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2). From the second point in the JLS:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>
> Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>
> **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.**

So if you want to sum the `string` value of the `0` `char` and the `string` value of the `1` `char` you explicitly need to convert them in string as follow:

```
String room = "901";

String roomNumber = String.valueof(room.charAt(1)) + String.valueof(room.charAt(2));
```

If you do that the `+` operator is considered a concatenation between strings and not as a sum between int.

Comment: *While using substring will solve the problem (as in the answer of @Giorgi Tsiklauri), this doesn't point to the real hidden question posted that is:* - I'm not sure I agree with you. OP clearly states "*I want to a new String "01"*", and `subString(int)` is a way to choose in this case (which was also accepted by OP). Apart of that, I also provide additional information which you can read a bit down. So, I'm not sure why you think that `subString()` does not solve/answer the problem, when OP thinks it does, and it actually does - considering what is the OP's question.

Comment: Where have you read the question you cite - *Why a concatenation between chars is not the same of a concatenation of two strings of size 1 ?* ?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri because the title says "How to concatenate chars...", not how to extract the last two chars

Comment: 1. That is an edited title of the question; 2. Even with the old title, question has never asked *why char+char evaluates to int?*. OP wanted to take the substring, which you could guess should you have read the question carefully. He also found my answer helpful and that doubles the justification of what I say.. I think you're just making up an interpretation of the question, answering something that has never been asked; 3. Moreover: as I said, I also provided an additional information which just explains the point you refer to.. but seems like you didn't pay attention to that as well.