# Creating Hash in Java

Tags: java, foreach, hashmap, hashcode, to-char

I came across this code which is using .toCharArray() to create a hashcode of a string which will be later used to store data in a HashMap.

```
    public static int generateHashCode(String s) {
    int code = 0;
    
    for(char next_character: s.toCharArray()) {
        code += next_character;
    }
    
    return code;
}
```

What I understand from this code is that it's using an enhanced for loop to traverse through each character of the string(Made array). What I don't understand is that how it's adding those "characters" to an "integer"-code. I changed the code to just print next_character and it printed all the individual characters of the strings.

Comment: try printing `(int) next_character` - will return the UTF-16  code of that character - and a character is an integral type by [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1-100-E) - it is printed as a character (not converted to integer representation, as other number)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What’s happening here is that the char is being promoted to an int, its value will be equal to the ASCII value.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: Oh, that makes sense but how's that happening? Does java automatically understand that the user is trying to add a character to an int and therefore converts the character to its ASCII equivalent number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8688668/2023052

Comment: `ASCII` only if it is not greater than `\u007f` (127)