# why is charAt(index)-1 function returning wrong output

Tags: java, for-loop, charat, string-function

```
    String s = "1234";
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i)-1);  
    }
```

In the above line of code , for the first iteration, i.e., when i=0, first line should print 1 and second one should print 0 but the second one is printing 48. Why is it so?

Comment: When you perform arithmetic on a `char`, you transform it to an `int`. The character `'1'` becomes the int 49.

Comment: To add to khelwood, `s.charAt(i)-1` vs `s.charAt(i-1)`. However, I'd guess this will just throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` during your first loop. The second line would end up being `s.charAt(-1)` basically.

Comment: Related (not the same): [In Java, is the result of the addition of two chars an int or a char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688668/in-java-is-the-result-of-the-addition-of-two-chars-an-int-or-a-char)

Answer (score 2):

```
s.charAt(i)-1
```

This line gets the character at index `i` and decreases it by one. The first thing you need to know is that characters have a numeric value as well, and you can do math with them. The ASCII value of the character "1" is 49 (take a look at the table: [https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Epattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html)). So, the `charAt(i)` call returns the char that represents `1`, and has a value of `49`, and then you decrease it by `1`, resulting in `48`.

You need to convert the character value to an Int before decreasing it. Try:

```
Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i)) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Java does not generally do math on characters. So as soon as you subtract 1 from a `char`, Java first converts it to `int`, then subtracts 1 from that `int`. As the other answer explains, `'1'` is converted to 49, so you get 48 after the subtraction.

If you wanted the char before `'1'`, just convert back to `char` before printing:

```
    String s = "1234";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        System.out.println((char) (s.charAt(i) - 1));
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 1
> 0
> 2
> 1
> 3
> 2
> 4
> 3
> ```

Then it works on letters and punctuation too:

```
    String s = "Wtf?";
```

> ```
> W
> V
> t
> s
> f
> e
> ?
> >
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is that you are getting the character value. You should try converting the string/char to an integer before doing any math to it.